# How to get the day from a DateTime

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following Oracle table and I want `the last (aka max) entry by aGroup and day where the timepart of dateTime in less than 00:00:15` (day should be extracted as the datepart of `dateTime`)

What would be the SQL query for it (I do not know how to extract the day from dateTime)?

```
              dateTime aGroup
2011-01-01 00:00:12      a
2011-01-01 00:00:31      a
2012-01-01 00:00:09      a
2012-01-01 00:00:03      a
2011-01-01 00:00:06      b
2011-01-01 00:00:14      b
2011-01-01 00:00:16      b
2012-01-01 00:00:16      b
2012-01-01 00:00:11      b
```

This is want I would expect as a result

```
              dateTime aGroup
2011-01-01 00:00:12      a
2012-01-01 00:00:09      a
2011-01-01 00:00:14      b
2012-01-01 00:00:11      b
```

Comment: it is by aGroup AND day

Comment: _“I do not know how to extract the day from dateTime”_ – http://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+sql+date+functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is my try using to_char

```
SELECT AGROUP, MAX(DATETIME) FROM MYTABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'SS') <'15'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'YYYY-MM-DD'), AGROUP
ORDER BY AGROUP
```

Comment: Thanks, It works on the example, but let suppose I have 20 columns and I want the result with all columns, when I do `SELECT MYTABLE.*, MAX(DATETIME) FROM MYTABLE...` it is not working anymore...

Comment: You cannot use * syntax with group by, if you have 20 columns (groups) than you must add all of these to the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses individually

Comment: Really? there is no workaround to this rule ? Once I have a ORDER BY clause I need to write all columns myself ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(DateTime), 
  aGroup
FROM 
  tablename
WHERE 
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(DateTime)) < 15
GROUP BY 
  DATE(DateTime), 
  aGroup
```

This will give you the largest time (less than 00:00:15) for each day for each aGroup.

**EDIT:** Updated to use `TIME_TO_SEC` for oracle

Answer (score 1):

The [TRUNC function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2127.htm) is very handy to extract days :

```
SELECT dateTime, aGroup
FROM
(
    SELECT dateTime
          , aGroup
          , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY aGroup, TRUNC(dateTime, 'DDD') ORDER BY dateTime DESC) as Rank
    FROM table
    WHERE (dateTime - TRUNC(dateTime, 'DDD')) * 24 * 3600 < 15
)
WHERE Rank = 1
```

The line

```
 WHERE (dateTime - TRUNC(dateTime, 'DDD')) * 24 * 3600 < 15
```

compute the difference in days between your current date and the start of the day.
Multiply by 24 and 3600 to have the number of seconds, and filter if it is lower than 15.

Answer (score 1):

```
select dateTime, agroup
  from (select dateTime, agroup, 
               row_number() over (partition by agroup, trunc(datetime)
                                  order by datetime desc) rn
          from yourtab
         where to_number(to_char(datetime, 'hh24miss')) < 15)
 where rn = 1
```

will do that. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4eb98/1

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about sqlfiddle, new to SQL, and I am pretty surprised of "once you put an GROUP BY clause you have to write any field yourself"... but it is what it is

Comment: Also this solution is very slow compared to others, is it expected ?